# Why does the code in my R Markdown run, but when I go to Knit it, it doesn't work? [Solved]

Tags: markdown

I ask and answer this in case someone else needs it.

One solution is to put the function you're trying to run on an object, and the object creation code itself, within the same code block. However, if you want to have some code you don't need to show the results of in one block, and code you do want to sow the results of in another block, this could be an issue.

Try getting rid of this code that's at the start of a markdown file by default (worked for me, and might save ye some time):

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```